# Eloquent "super-eager" nested query possible?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, relation, subquery

Mates, 
my first post, searching and trying different solutions and approaches - and finally ended here asking.

I have a database with several related tables. A customer has a location, which has several settings (lifecycle eg. plan, build, run) and each setting has different circuits. Basically:

customers->locations->settings->circuits

Now I want a list of locations with setting and circuit information, where the supplier of the circuit is selected.

How would I write this query with eloquent? Here is what I tried so far, but it seems to ignore the "where supplier" clause...

```
$locations = Locations::with(
    ['settings' => function($query) use ($request)
        {
            $query->with(
                ['circuits' =>function($query2) use ($request)
                    {
                        $query2->where('supplier', $request->supplier);
                    }
                ]
            );                  
        }
    ])
    ->where('customer_id', $customers_id)
    ->orderBy('country')
    ->orderBy('city')
    ->get();
```

I'm sure, that all the "hasMany" and "belongsTo" extensions are available.
Thanks for reading & answering
udowsky

Update: Working Code, based on Enver's hint:

```
$locations = Locations::with('settings')
    ->whereHas('settings.circuits', function($query) use ($request)
        {
            $query->where('supplier', $request->supplier);
        }
        )
    ->where('customer_id', $report->customers_id)
    ->orderBy('country')
    ->orderBy('city')
    ->get();
```

HasManyThrough approach also works smooth:

Extending the Locations model:

```
public function circuits()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Circuits', '\App\Settings');
}
```

and then use this query:

```
$locations = Locations::with('circuits')
    ->whereHas('circuits', function($query) use ($request)
        {
            $query->where('supplier', $request->supplier);
        }
    )
    ->where('customer_id', $report->customers_id)
    ->orderBy('country')
    ->orderBy('city')
    ->get();
```

Thank you all!

Comment: Have you tried nested relation in with `with('settings.circuts')` or define a HasManyThrough relation?

Comment: Thanks Harven! - tested the "with('settings.circuits') approach, which still leads to the same result. HasManyThrough still to test. First need to read documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested relation query with eager loading.

Example:

```
$relation_sort = 'asc';
$nested_sort = 'desc';

$result = Model::with([
   'relation' => function($query) use($relation_sort){
      $query->orderBy('relation_column', $relation_sort);
   },
   'relation.nested' => function($query) use($nested_sort){
      $query->orderBy('nested_relation_column', $nested_sort);
   }
])->whereHas('relation', function($query){
    //Relation exists check.
    $query->where('price', '>', 100);
})->whereHas('relation.nested', function($query) use($search_param){
    //Nested Relation search.
    $query->where('search_column', 'LIKE', $search_param);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Enver - this helped! Will update the 'question' above with the working code based on your hint.

Comment: You are welcome. If your question answered, please mark.